# Disabling Num Lock On External keyboard

Tags: laptop, usb, keyboard, numlock

I use a external keyboard for my laptop (Pc Specialist custom build) when I go into meeting and then when the meeting is done I use my integrated keyboard on my laptop. Now when I disconnect the external keyboard it turns my Num Lock on so when I try to login I am using Num Lock and it is getting really annoying.

Ive looked into VBS scripts and Ive tried changing the setting within regedit.

I am been stupid or just looking in the wrong place?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
McCall

Comment: Duplicate: [hit num lock when I plug in keyboard](http://superuser.com/q/858592/241386)