# Windows 7 event for plugging in USB keyboard

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, windows-task-scheduler, numlock

I would like to use task scheduler to toggle num lock as I plug or unplug my keyboard from my laptop. I use it equally with and without the external keyboard, so both the default settings are equally inconvenient. Is there an event I can use to schedule a enable/disable num lock task?

Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't find any events for plugging/unplugging USB keyboards (only for storage devices). It should be possible to [log](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html) keyboard events but I don't know what messages that program specifically monitors.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/863258/138343) helps. If you manage to solve it, don't forget to share the answer with us below. Good luck. :)