# Where can I view IO device history in Windows (8/7)?

Tags: logging, history

Essentially I need to view the IO devices that have been connected/disconnected in the past, and when they'd been connected.

If such logs don't exist, how can I record them?

I was able to find multiple resources for viewing storage device activity, but nothing on I/O devices like keyboard, printer, etc.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/913262/windows-7-event-for-plugging-in-usb-keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

This information is recorded in `C:\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log` . It is a text file that is appended to whenever devices are connected or disconnected. Devices are always identified by their plug-and-play IDs, and sometimes by more friendly names. The log indicates the associated .INF files and driver files.