# Disable laptop num lock

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hp-elitebook, numlock

I have an HP EliteBook that is sometimes docked.

When the laptop is undocked, I generally **do not** want the num lock to be on.  It would prevent me from entering normal letters.

When the laptop is docked, I generally **do** want the num lock to be on, since my USB keyboard has a numeric keypad that I like to use for, you know, numbers.

Every time I dock or undock my laptop, I find that typing doesn't work the way I want and I then toggle the num lock.

Is there some way for the docked USB keyboard numlock to **not** turn on the silly laptop keyboard numlock?

Or, if there's no other option, is there any way to disable the laptop's num lock altogether since I'll probably never want to use it?

(I'm running Window 7 Pro 64 bit.)

Comment: Which operating system and release/version/edition? Unless you want to hack the hardware (which I wouldn't recommend), this is more of a software than a hardware question.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I've added OS info.  I didn't think that would matter.  This used to happen on my Dell laptop, but there was a BIOS setting I could change.  I couldn't find one for this HP laptop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently disable num lock in windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/688889/permanently-disable-num-lock-in-windows)

Comment: possible duplicate: [hit num lock when I plug in keyboard](http://superuser.com/q/858592/241386)

Answer (score 1):

Create an archive like `DisableNumlock.reg`, and paste the code below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard]
"InitialKeyboardIndicators"="0"
"KeyboardDelay"="1"
"KeyboardSpeed"="31"

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard]
"InitialKeyboardIndicators"="0"
"KeyboardDelay"="1"
"KeyboardSpeed"="31"
```

When you want do ENABLE the numlock, create another archive EnableNumlock.reg and paste the code below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard]
"InitialKeyboardIndicators"="2"
"KeyboardDelay"="1"
"KeyboardSpeed"="31"

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard]
"InitialKeyboardIndicators"="2"
"KeyboardDelay"="1"
"KeyboardSpeed"="31"
```

Comment: This appears to be a registry change that turns off the num lock.  How would I use it to solve my problem?

Comment: Awnser edited. I think that is the best solution. 2 archives, to enable or disable the numlock.

Comment: I'm still not sure how this helps.  I want the numlock to turn off when I undock.  Now instead of remembering to hit the numlock key, I need to remember to run this script.